# Jquery onfocus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text area and I'm trying to run a function based on when the spacebar is hit. However, the code is not working and I can't seem to figure out why. It looks right from what research I've done.

Here's the text area definition:

`<div class="DivWithScroll" id="my_text" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" onkeydown="return onKeyDown(event)">`

Here is the Jquery code that I have on my page so far trying to run the `.onFocus()`

```
$('document').ready(function () {
        $('#my_text').focus(function () {
            $('#my_text').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == '32') {
                    alert('space');
                }
            });
            alert("Focused!");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason to set up onkeydown when the focus event is triggered? Also, I don't see any myKeyPress or onKeyDown functions.

Comment: lmao, whoops *not working*

Comment: works in chrome, i imagine this might be a browser specific issue. what browsers have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you're using alert. [Stop using alert for troubleshooting](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/)

this works -

```
$('#my_text').focus(function () {
    $('#my_text').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == '32') {
            console.log('space');
        }
    });
    console.log("Focused!");
});
```

It would likely be better to use `keyup()` in this circumstance too, to avoid issues on when the key is pressed.
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/7cqawhf6/3/)

Comment: Then OP says "here's the text area definition" and gives a div. In a less denotative sense, a contenteditable div is a "text area".

Comment: In any case, here http://jsfiddle.net/7cqawhf6/1/ we see a better suggestion and here http://jsfiddle.net/7cqawhf6/2/ we see the OP's specified construction. Notice that the OP's specified construction doesn't break. Changing it back to alerts doesn't fix the issue, and this is not the solution to his problem. It is more likely that the problem are the random event handlers on the DIV itself.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis your second example does not work across browsers.